# Is there an entry-level circadian model of serotonin, ghrelin, dopamine and the sense of well being?

Tags: human-biology, endocrinology, circadian-rhythms

I've long been interested in circadian rhythms and recently came across a variety of articles that appear to indicate that the following neurotransmitters, transferases and hormones are connected. There are mentions of some circadian rhythmicity and maintaining homeostasis for these compounds([Are serotonin levels in humans affected by light?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/5554/are-serotonin-levels-in-humans-affected-by-light)):

- [Serotonin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serotonin#Gauge_of_social_situation)
- [Dopamine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dopamine#Functions_in_the_brain)
- [Melatonin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melatonin#Circadian_rhythm)
- HIOMT, NAT
- [Ghrelin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghrelin#Mechanism_of_action)
- [Leptin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leptin#Function)

Additionally, their expression is related to [Suprachiasmatic Nucleus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suprachiasmatic_nucleus) and light exposure.

**I'm interested if there's a good article or a talk that discusses the homeostatic system that those compounds are a part of.** I'm particularly interested in their effect on the feeling of well being.

It seems to me that all these compounds are in some way related to moving and feeding. However, I cannot wrap my mind around multiple separate articles that describe how, and am looking for a single paper that may shed light on the connection between these compounds.

Comment: Most hormones have some circadian/ultradian/infradian component. These questions are somehow related to what you're asking: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2732/do-men-have-significant-hormonal-cycles http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1982/what-can-the-timing-of-human-urination-tell-about-the-humans-physical-condition/ http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3590/how-are-long-time-periods-measured-in-biological-systems/